# Install 2 SDK for Push Service

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, urbanairship.com, exacttarget

Can I install 2 Pusk SDK Service in an app **`(Android and iOS)`**? we need to migrate from ExactTarget to Parse or UrbanAirship, but managers need time to migrate, so, we want to use ExactTarget for Marketing automation process (already configured)  AND use Parse internally for calling API triggers notifications.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on native android apps then i suggest to use google cloud messaging for sending push notifications,in my experience i use UrbanAirship for Web apps only,using multiple SDK is not good idea because if you are working with one technology/process for notifications then its easy to configure any problem if occurred in future..

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing 'wrong' with using two SDKs to handle push notifications.  For iOS, delivery is handled by APNS (Apple), and for Android, delivery is handled by GCM (Google).  So, the delivery of the notifications will not change.  The SDKs that are provided by the services you listed above are normally used to:

1) Handle the arrival of the notifications
2) Record/manage the audience to which notifications can be sent to
3) Provide analytics for the notifications that were just sent.

The biggest concern/issue that you probably will have will be the handling of your audience.  Services such as Urban Airship and Parse, provide the convenience of managing your device information.  Without going into too much detail, you have to know WHO you are sending notifications.  Depending on which provider you choose, you will need to migrate that device information from old to new.  Here's some links that will get you going on that, but let me know if you have any other questions:

Apple: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Google:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref